# SPListItem access to lookup column not work

Tags: list, lookup-column, splistitem

I have one list definition like this:

```
<ContentType ID="0x01..." Name="CNT_List" Group="List Content" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Code" DisplayName="Code" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_ShortDescription" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Description" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Date" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Country_Lookup" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Regions_Lookup" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_StartDate" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_EndDate" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Status_Lookup" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_Late" />
      <FieldRef ID="{guid}" Name="PRF_PreIntProgress" />
      ...
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
```

I'm trying retriving data with following code:

```
List<MyModel> model = new List<MyModel>();
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("CNT_List");

if (list != null)
{
   SPListItemCollection coll = list .Items;

   foreach (SPListItem icoll in coll)
   {
      model.Add(Mapper.SPListItemToModel(icoll));
   }
}
```

Now, I'm trying mapping data with following code:

```
public static MyMode SPListItemToModel(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        if (listItem != null)
        {
            MyModel model = new MyModel();

            model.ID = listItem.ID;
            model.Code = listItem["PRF_Code"].AsString();
            model.ShortDescr = listItem["PRF_ShortDescription"].AsString();
            model.Status = listItem["PRF_Status_Lookup"].AsInt();
            ...
```

If I try to execute my code I obtain one ArgoumentException error at line:

```
model.Status = listItem["PRF_Status_Lookup"].AsInt();
```

Which is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value as below:

```
model.Status = ((SPFieldLookupValue)listItem["PRF_Status_Lookup"]).LookupValue;
```

You can refer the members of SPFieldLookupValue from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue_members.aspx).

Comment: Hi Nisarg, I've changed my code with your fix but it not work. "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

Comment: if the value of listItem["PRF_Status_Lookup"] is empty you will get that error, validate that the data is not empty